# How to pass a List from JSP to Controller class in Java

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jsp-tags

How to pass a List from JSP to Controller class with Spring mvc in Java?

Regards
Sony K Koshy

Comment: Do you want to pass list of values through http (GET/POST)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@ModelAttribute` for your bean to be used in the form. Please check below demo code.

```
public class MusicianRequest {
    private List<Musican> musicians = new ArrayList<Musician>();
}
```

Use List or array for your data so you are able to access them by index with jstl.

Then in your JSP have:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="musicianRequest" method="PUT" action="" >
    <c:forEach items="${musicianRequest.musicians}" var="musician" varStatus="loop">
        <tr>
            <td><form:checkboxes items="${musician.instruments}" path="musicians[${loop.index}].instruments" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```